# How do I make a plain ole C-function an Objective-C selector?

Tags: objective-c, function-pointers, selector

I want to point to a plain ole C-function from Objective-C. Specifically, I am pointing to some OpenGL functions. I want to point to this function from an entry in an NSDictionary.

So is there a way to turn a C function pointer into a SEL?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in an `NSValue`.

```
[dictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:&myFunction] forKey:theKey];
```

Then when you extract it later, just call `-pointerValue` to get a void* pointer back (which you can cast to your function type).

Comment: Yah, I was leaning this way. Just thought there might be some nifty Obj-C introspective goodness I could use. Cheers.

Comment: The only real alternative is to wrap the functions in Obj-C methods as @ericgorr suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way, but why not have an Obj-C method that will call the plain ole C-Function?

You can then make the Obj-C method the SEL that you call.